# Angular 4 Getting "Cannot find name" errors during unit test

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, typescript

I am new to Angular 4 and many of its trappings like Typescript, the CLI, use of NodeJS and NPM, and many others. I have successfully figured most things out.

However, I have recently tried adding unit tests to my code and I'm encountering a variety of problems. I gave up on trying to unit test the router, as the issues were proving difficult to troubleshoot and resolve. Instead, I'm trying to do a simple unit test on one of my services.

Whenever I make a spec file with a test that does nothing, it works. This is an example:

```
describe('MyTest', () => {
    it('does nothing', () => {});
});
```

However, as soon as I attempt to do a real test by injecting a reference to one of my Angular services, I get a bunch of errors that all say "Cannot find name '###'" where ### are the names custom types that I declared in a separate set of files.

The Angular CLI seems to have no problem including these types, but the test environment is. What am I missing?

The following is an example of what is failing:

```
import { MyService } from './my-service.ts';
import { TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {} from 'jasmine';

describe('MyTest', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [ MyService ]
        });
    });

    it('should be created', inject([MyService], (service: MyService) => {
        expect(service).toBeTruthy();
    }));
});
```

Comment: Did you import `MyService`?

Comment: Yes. I imported it like follows:
    import { MyService } from './my-service.service.ts';

Comment: Not sure, can you post the code for the constructor and ngOnInit for MyService? Normally you get problems with providers but I've not seen "Cannot find name '###'" before.